# Emailing a section of an Excel sheet in an email as a PDF attachment with a button

Tags: vba, excel, email, pdf

I have the code in the title above, the code below will send a PDF of my Excel sheet in an email to an email address which is stated in a cell. My problem with this is the name it gives to the PDF file is the file name followed by the tab name.

How would I edit the code below so that it gives the file a name which is stated in a cell in the sheet?

```
Sub savePDFandEmailPayPlan()

Dim strPath As String, strFName As String
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

 'Create PDF of active sheet only
strPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"  trailing "\"

strFName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
strFName = Left(strFName, InStrRev(strFName, ".") - 1) & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    strPath & strFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = Range("BH4")
    .CC = Range("BH6")
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("BH8")
    .Body = Range("BH10") & vbCr
    .Attachments.Add strPath & strFName
    .Display  
    '.Send     
End With

Kill strPath & strFName
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strFName = Sheets("mySheet").Range("A1")`

Adjust for your desired sheet and name range.

Comment: Perfect!...I tried something similar before but when I did, it was not attaching the file but I must have made a mistake because this line works.